# I am getting code 1 error while installing ops

Tags: python-3.x

I am unable to install ops because of a code 1 error

I tried updating pip, reinstalling python, updating setup tool, installing easy_install

'''
pip install ops 
Collecting ops
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/40/24e083823c39b485cb5473e62124e9c38cc0fce10f075d3189acf173b56f/ops-0.4.7.tar.gz     ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:     ERROR: Traceb
'''

Comment: What do you mean by "code 1 error"?

Comment: ''' pip install ops Collecting ops
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/40/24e083823c39b485cb5473e62124e9c38cc0fce10f075d3189acf173b56f/ops-0.4.7.tar.gz ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: ERROR: Traceb '''